# angularjs country code look up from jsonfile via $http request

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angularjs-scope, angularjs-http

I am trying to look up country codes from a json file to get the full country names:

```
$scope.fullname = function (option) {
    $http.get('files/names.json').success(function (data) {     
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {         
            if (data[i].key === option)
                return data[i].value;
        }
    })
};
```

and in the markup:

```
<td class="secondary-text">{{fullname (list.countrycode) }}</td>
```

I get serious errors and browser gets crashed. 
Could somebody help me solve this? how can I get the list into memory and then look up the country codes from that list?

my json file is like this:

```
{
    "BD": "Bangladesh",
    "BE": "Belgium",
    "BF": "Burkina Faso",
    "BG": "Bulgaria",
    "BA": "Bosnia and Herzegovina",
    "BB": "Barbados",
    "WF": "Wallis and Futuna",
    "BL": "Saint Barthelemy",
    "BM": "Bermuda",
    "BN": "Brunei",
...
```

Comment: what is the error? can you post more details into your question? Also is the country.io your site and just want to refer the json file in your project? or receive the list of countries from an external site? The top and bottom of the question is conflicting each other

Comment: Break it down and debug. Try putting a debugger on first line of code and in .success callback, use debugger to know exactly where it all goes wrong.

Comment: @lifejuggler the site is not mine, i am just refering to it for you to see the structure of my json file. maybe my iteration is not valid based on this structure of the json file.

Comment: @someangular simple way to check is use this: http://jsonlint.com/ to see if your json makes sense... if it does then maybe post the console errors or server errors to get a better sense of which part is causing your system to crash

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of Course the browser will crash with this line:

```
<td class="secondary-text">{{fullname (list.countrycode) }}</td>
```

Do you know how many times the `fullname()` function gets called? EVERY digest cycle! Which happen a lot of times.

In your controller you should create a **single call** to the server, directly from within the controller:

```
$http.get('files/names.json').success(function (data) {   
    $scope.fullnames = data;      
})
```

And in the view you can do something like

```
<td class="secondary-text" ng-repeat="(key,value) in fullnames" ng-if="key  == list.countrycode">{{value }}</td>
```

I don't know what your HTML look like, but you might also improve it by using one-time binding, like:

```
    <td class="secondary-text" ng-repeat="(key,value) in ::fullnames" ng-if="key  == list.countrycode">{{value }}</td>
```